# Making a user input equal to the value of a variable

Tags: python, if-statement, variables, user-input

So I'm pretty new to python and currently making a text based game. I want to give random generated code pieces to the player, then asking them to input the correct combination. I stored the numbers in a list, scrambled them and joined them together to get a four digit number in a random order from a list of four numbers. Since the numbers are random, I don't know the combination, so I can't ask for the exact four digit number. I tried to make the user input equal to the variable in which I stored the four digit number, but it doesn't work. It either doesn't recognise the correct number or say that 'int' object is not callable. Can someone help with this?

```
coderan = random.sample(safecode, len(safecode))

def convert(coderan):
    num = [str(n) for n in coderan]
    code = int("".join(num))
    return code

compcode = (convert(coderan))

print(type(compcode))

print(compcode)

c2 = int(input())
time.sleep(1)
ans = 'incorrect'
while(ans=='incorrect'):
    if(c2()==compcode):
        time.sleep(1)
        print(SCENE6COMP)
        ans = 'correct'
    else:
        time.sleep(1)
        print("That's not the right combination. Try again! ")
        c2 = input()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a mistake in your if-statements condition. With `c2()` you call the int-object stored in c2 (which your error message states). To fix this, your if-statement should look like this:

```
if(c2==compcode):
    …
```

Comment: Thank you, that solved it! I also needed to convert the compcode to a string and ask in a str(input()) and it works now!